# Form Input with Pattern

Tags: php, html

I need help, first character in the input must be "M" or "S"

```
<input type="text" name="trackid" id="trackid" value="<?= set_value('trackid'); ?>" class="form-control form-control-user text-center" placeholder="TrackID" required>
```

Comment: You want in php, right? Looking at your tags I assume I am right

Answer (score 0):

The below code will check it for the requirements and if they are not met echo an error message.

```
$trackid = //whatever is the input;
$firstChar = substr($trackid, 0, 1);
if ($firstChar == "M" || $firstChar == "S") {
    echo "This input is fine";
}
else {
    echo "The starting character of the input should be M or S";
}
```

Comment: consider choosing it as correct answer if this answers your question...